# Adding data to table on same page

Tags: tables, data-tables, data-entry

so here is interesting question

I have a data table, where person adds data at the end of the table, current design is following, input table is same width as data column

[image]

Unfortunately it is not solution, since sometimes there are way more columns and long input labels ( you can see one of the labels of input )

so I designed a solution but still I dont like it much since it takes up too much of vertical space, once again way too much in case of many data in a table.

[image]

does anyone has better ux solution for this, please note that we have to make data adding on same page, opening it in new page is not an option, I also though about opening accordion on add table data, but client wants it to be visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of space, it's just a matter of knowing how to manage it.

For example, I don't see it necessary for the title and content to go in line:

[image]

From there you can modify the size as desired, for example `rate`, `payment` and `area` may need less width.